# Check string for an array item and match it

Tags: c#, arrays, string, match, string-matching

I have a string and an array and i want to check the string and find if the string contains any string from the array.

My array will contain about 10 elements max.

```
string[] stringArray = { "apple", "banana", "orange" };
string text="I want an apple";

public static string getItem(string text)
{
    //check text for stringArray items
    //return item (apple, banana, orange)
}
string item = getItem(text);
```

So what im looking for is to create a method that returns the item from. Also i'd like to know if there any alternatives ways to do this with Enum or List<>.

Finally i made my method like this

```
public static string getItem(string text)
        {
            string[] stringArray = { "Apple", "Banana", "Orange" };
            string item = stringArray.Where(s => text.ToUpper().Contains(s)).DefaultIfEmpty("None").FirstOrDefault();;
            return item;
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With just a bit of LINQ-iness, this because quite easy:

```
return stringArray.Where(s => text.Contains(s)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This assumes that you want to return only the first matched string and that you want to do a case-sensitive comparison. If not, minor modifications can be made relatively easily to change things.

The code above will also work equally as well if your source is a `List<string>` as well (actually, anything that implements `IEnumerable<string>` will work in its place). An `Enum`, on the other hand, is not the proper fit for this kind of thing.

Comment: Nice i got it but what if there is no nothing that matches in my array list. I want if there is no match to return/get "No match". Should i use this with a simple if?

if (item == null)
                item = "Cannot Match";

Comment: @Incognito - You can stick DefaultIfEmpty("Cannot Match") between the Where and FirstOrDefault which would cause FirstOrDefault to return your desired result if no match was found.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Another last thing is that i want to ignore case sensitive.

Comment: @Incognito - You'll have to use IndexOf instead of Contains. Look for the overload that takes StringComparison: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx

Comment: I converted my text to Uppercase it seems more easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your array, you can make it a `List<string>`.  And then in your `getItem()`, you can do:

```
List<string> stringList; // populate how you see fit
string text="I want an apple";

public static string getItem(string text)
{
    foreach(var s in stringList)
    {
        if(text.Contains(s))
        {
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

A `List<>` isn't required for the `foreach` loop.  It's just nice to have.

Comment: There's no reason to change the string array to a list of strings. This code will work with both.

Comment: Right.  But he asked if there was a way to use a `List<>`.  I was just showing the way.